# weird: Red vid doesn't take into account line break in box if it has background color

Tags: red

1°) align: 'left doesn't work (is my syntax right ?)

2°) ^/ sometimes not taken into account:

```
    view layout [
        box 400x400
        font [align: 'left size: 40 color: red] "line1^/line2"
    ]
```

[image]

but if I just add white to box:

```
    view layout [
        box white 400x400
        font [align: 'left size: 40 color: red] "line1^/line2"
    ]
```

[image]

Comment: This seems like a bug that should be filed in the red github. Also, try reaching out to people in one of the red language gitter channels.

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow is not the place where bugs or issues for Red language should be reported. We have specific channels for that. Please report the issue on Red's [issue tracker](https://github.com/red/red/issues).